# How is transaction success defined in ConfirmedBlock.proto?

Tags: bigtable

As of Solana Labs v1.18, the ConfirmedBlock.proto definitions are undocumented and ambiguous.

The following structs are part of the [Protobuf version of TransactionStatusMeta](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/v1.18.6/storage-proto/proto/confirmed_block.proto):

```
message TransactionStatusMeta {
    TransactionError err = 1;
    ...
}

message TransactionError {
    bytes err = 1;
}
```

What is a reliable way to determine transaction success here?

1. Is it the absence of the `TransactionError` submessage?
2. Is it the absence of the `err` field in an existing `TransactionError` submessage?
3. Is it a zero length `err` in an existing `TransactionError` submessage?
4. Is it a specific value in a non-empty `err`? If so, how is the `err` field encoded?

Has anyone tested these criteria against Solana Fndn's mainnet archives?